# Drupal 6: Drupal_goto() passing variable

Tags: php, variables, drupal

So I have a function that have this destination link: http://link/to/$id
It's work when I use:

```
 <a href="?q=mymodule/option/$id">Targeted</a>
```

But I need to change it to submit form because I need to passing more than one $id. So, I thougt it was good if I used drupal_goto() rather than link option.

```
drupal_goto('mymodule/option/$id');
drupal_goto('mymodule/option/'.$id);
drupal_goto('mymodule/option/', $id);
```

Those are not working. It alwayas go to http://link/mymodule/option withot passing $id variable. How to do this correctly in drupal 6? Thanks before.